# how to send email automatically once in a day in asp.net and host on go daddy server

Tags: asp.net

I want to make application in asp.net which send Birthday email automatically once in a day and hosted on go daddy server. which type of application i should make..windows service.on scheduler job. or any thing else? please help me.

Comment: Yes, you'll need something like a windows service. Just run a timer inside and send out the email once a day.

Comment: Take a look at [Easy Background Tasks in ASP.NET by by Jeff Atwood](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/) and [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Comment: I make windows service that run locally send email automatically..i can host windows service on go daddy server or not?